# Preventing tunneling of small, fast objects

Tags: c#, collision-detection

I'm making a basic shooter game with my friend and i have encountered a problem. I kind of know solution this but i just cant implement it. This is my first game made with XNA/MonoGame and i'm not too good with c# either. So my problem is collision detection between bullets and enemies. Sometimes bullets go trough enemies and sometimes they hit. Problem seems to be in my collision detection code because it only detects one item in my array list. This ([sweep test](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131790/simple_intersection_tests_for_games.php?page=3)) might be the solution as someone suggested but it looks too complicated for me. This might be so simple to fix but like i said i just cant figure out how to do it. I'll post my code and hope that someone can help. Thanks!

This is my main class where it should remove killed enemies:

```
                    foreach (enemy enem in enemies)
                    {

                        enem.Update(graphics.GraphicsDevice);

                    }

                    LoadEnemies();

                    foreach (bullet bull in bullets)
                    {

                        bull.Update();

                    }

                    //WSAD movement

                    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
                    {
                        charRect.X += 6;
                    }

                    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
                    {
                        charRect.X -= 6;
                    }

                    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
                    {
                        charRect.Y -= 6;
                    }

                    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
                    {
                        charRect.Y += 6;
                    }

                    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
                    {
                        LoadBullets();
                    }

                    //Screen collision detection

                    if (charRect.X <= -41)
                    {
                        charRect.X = -41;
                    }

                    if (charRect.Y <= 0)
                    {
                        charRect.Y = 0;
                    }

                    if (charRect.Y >= 400)
                    {
                        charRect.Y = 400;
                    }

                    if (charRect.X >= 632)
                    {
                        charRect.X = 632;
                    }

                    base.Update(gameTime);

                    break;

                }

            case State.Menu:
                {

                    playButton = new button(Content.Load<Texture2D>("playButton"), new Vector2(100, 100));

                    playButton.Update();

                    break;

                }

            case State.GameOver:
                {

                    break;

                }

            }

        }

    public void LoadEnemies()
    {

        if (enemySpawnInterval >= 1)
        {

            enemySpawnInterval = 0;

            if (enemies.Count < 4)
            {

                int randY = r.Next(1, 600);

                enemies.Add(new enemy(Content.Load<Texture2D>("enemyChar"), new Vector2(800, randY)));

            }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Count; i++)
        {

            if (!enemies[i].isOnScreen)
            {

                enemies.RemoveAt(i);
                i--;

            }

            if (enemies[i].enemyIsHit)
            {

                enemies.RemoveAt(i);
                enemyKilled.Play();
                i--;

            }

        }

    }
```

This is place where i spawn bullets and enemies:

```
    Texture2D enemyChar;
    Vector2 position;

    public static Rectangle enemyBox;

    public Boolean enemyIsHit = false;
    public Boolean isOnScreen = true;

    public enemy(Texture2D newEnemyChar, Vector2 newPos)
    {

        enemyChar = newEnemyChar;
        position = newPos;

    }

    public void Update(GraphicsDevice graphics)
    {

        enemyBox = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, enemyChar.Width, enemyChar.Height);

        if (enemyBox.Intersects(bullet.bulletBox))
        {

            enemyIsHit = true;

        }

        if (position.Y <= 0 || position.Y >= graphics.Viewport.Height - enemyChar.Height)
        {

            position.Y = 100;

        }

        if (position.X < -80)
        {

            isOnScreen = false;

        }

        position.X -= 5;

    }
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection#A_posteriori_.28discrete.29_versus_a_priori_.28continuous.29

Comment: That is a little bit too hard i would say.

Comment: It's probably much simpler than it looks. Wikipedia sucks at presenting information in a helpful manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a double loop, something like (in pseudocode):

```
for each enemy{
    for each bullet{
        if bullet intersect enemy{
            //handle hit
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Pseudocode for gradually moving bullets during collision detection, goes in place of moving bullets anywhere else:

```
for each bullet{
    loop 10 times{
        move bullet 1/10 of original speed
        for each enemy{
            if bullet intersect enemy{
                //handle hit
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That works, kind of. It detects some hits and its better than my old one, but some hits don't get detected. Could you suggest any good collision detection frameworks/libraries?

Comment: It only works as far as the bullets travel a distance that is reasonably smaller than the size of an enemy per update. Say if your enemies are 10 units wide and the bullets travel 20 units per update a bullet may be on one side of an enemy during one update and on the far side during the next. A faster update rate with smaller movement per update could solve this problem. Usually I'd recommend separating your physics update rate and your rendering update rate so that you can easily run the physics as fast as needed.

Comment: Based on your explanation this is too hard for my first game. I still want to complete it though so ill just mess around and try to get some progress done. Maybe even try Farseer Physics!

Comment: Alternately you could cheat a little with the bullets, move them gradually during the collision detection phase and detect collisions for each intermediate position. I'll post some new pseudocode. Using a physics library is probably more trouble than help for such a simple job, it has to be set up properly for your specific task, so I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: Its getting better, but its not quite there. Now when you tap space, bullets work like they should, but when you hold space they go forwards then backwards then forwards again. Also enemies don't disappear right after i hit them. If i hit 3 enemies nothing happens, and after few seconds all of those 3 disappear at the same time.

Comment: It is hard to say what is wrong, sounds like you have got some unrelated issues as well. Do try to be sure that you are not handling the same enemy being hit multiple times. Simply putting a flag on the enemies and bullets that are hit during the loop and handling removing them afterwards may be an advantage.

Comment: Ok, it doesn't matter anymore. I'm sure i can fix so small problem. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to treat your objects as singular points rather than polygons.  By doing this you can draw a line between an objects last position and its current position and then do a line intersection check to see if they have passed through each other.

Eg.

Your enemy is at (0,0) and moves to (10,10) in 1 time step.
Your Bullet is at (10,0) and moves to (0,10) in 1 time step.

create a line for the enemy from (0,0) to (10,10) and one for the bullet from (10,0) to (0,10)

if you do this on a piece of graph paper it is easy to see that they intersect. But how do we get our program to do that. I have found a very nice tutorial and code example at `Third Party Ninjas` that shows just that.

Check out the post: http://thirdpartyninjas.com/blog/2008/10/07/line-segment-intersection/

specifically the `processIntersection()` method in the `Game1.cs` file.

Comment: That will be faster i guess? Well, if i need ever better detection, i will use that. For now eBusiness's solution is good enough. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use ray casting? If your bullets are moving too fast to be detected normally during your update you can check to see if there is something between their last location and current location. While this example may be a bit much to digest if you are not very familiar with C# it does include the source code which you can walk yourself through.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15604/Ray-casting-in-a-2D-tile-based-environment

Comment: While this can be a bit slow, it should in theory run up to 10x faster than moving the bullet 1/10th of it's velocity 10 times in a loop and checking for collisions at each point.

Comment: As a side note, the length of the ray should be the distance your bullet has traveled since the last update.